# Flutter how to show images in stack

Tags: arrays, listview, flutter, stack, networkimageview

I have some network image urls in an array. I want to show the images on each other like a stack. I used listview but it is showing them under together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Stack widget is what you need. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html and to position your images you can use the Positioned widget. This video may help you a lot https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

Comment: But how about getting data from array?